# AllowDrop on a DataGrid Row based on mouse position

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am wondering, if I can use an `AllowDrop` on a `datagrid` row, instead of the `DataGrid` itself.

I'll explain :

I can do `allowDrop` on `datagrid`, and then, I tried to identified the row, where I drop my item.

The thing is, it keep the row selected before I drop the item. Because when I drag an item on a row in the `datagrid`, it doesn't do the select event.

So, is there a way to, either put `AllowDrop` on a row, so I can identify it more easily, or either way, identify the good row, with the position of the mouse, when I drop the item.

**edit : so, after putting `AllowDrop` on a Row, this still doesn't work. The problem is, to be able to selected a `Row`, when I drop an item on it. Is this possible?**

Can I, get the Selected row, based on the mouse position (or the drop item position)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler to the DataGrid for the DataGrid.LoadingRow event:

- The DataGrid_LoadingRow event will be passed DataGridRowEventArgs.
- The DataGridRowEventArgs contains the row that is being loading.

Example:

```
    private void MyDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.AllowDrop = true;
    }
```

Comment: But that doesn't change anything because it does not select the row, where I drop my item...

Comment: Zaphod - check out my new answer "How to get the row under the mouse". Maybe that will be the trick you need.

Answer (score 0):

## How to get the row under the mouse:

```
    private void DataGrid_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow dataGridRow = null;

        var point = e.GetPosition(null);
        var elements = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(point, theDataGrid);
        if (elements != null && elements.Count() > 0)
        {
            var rowQuery = from gridRow in elements where gridRow is DataGridRow select gridRow as DataGridRow;
            dataGridRow = rowQuery.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```